# Identify the location of the last entry with a particular value in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list (Table) consisting of "True"s and "False"s. I would like to identify the position in the list of the last entry that takes the value "False". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `Last[Position[list,False,1]][[1]]`?

Comment: Ironically, there is a command `FirstPosition` but no `LastPosition`.

Comment: I am sure i saw a question very similar to this but can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FirstPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html) on [`Reverse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html)d input list:

```
Length[list] + 1 - FirstPosition[False] @ Reverse[list]
```

Alternatively, use [`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html):

```
Last @ PositionIndex[list][False]
```

or [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html):

```
Last @ Position[False][list]
```

or [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
SequenceCases[list, a:{___, False} :> Length[a]]
```